# Get Token's Name with Reflection API

Tags: php, reflection

I want to find the token's name passed by augment into a function.

```
class Norm
{
    const STR_NORM = 0;
    const INT_NORM = 0;
}

function foo($Arg1, $Arg2 = NULL)
{
    getConstName($Arg1); # Should Return STR_NORM;
    return $Arg1, $Arg2;
}

echo foo(Norm::STR_NORM);
```

Is there any way to implement getConstName via the [PHP Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because inside `foo()`, the value of `$Arg` is just the integer 0.  It has no way of knowing that this value came from a const.

For example, what should be output by the following example?

```
class Norm
{
    const STR_NORM = 0;
    const INT_NORM = 2;
}

echo foo( Norm::STR_NORM+2 );
echo foo( Norm::INT_NORM );
```

Should both of these echoes output `INT_NORM`?

Comment: Good Point. I'll have to have a think about my problem them.

Comment: I think the usual solution is to make each const a distinct value.